# React Native - When I run 'detox build -c android' it says "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: android, react-native, detox

So I've essentially followed all the instructions in the Detox documentation for getting a Detox testing environment and suite set up for Android in a React Native project. For my Android setup, I added the native detox dependency to my root build.gradle. I did NOT set up Detox as a compiling dependency because the docs said it was an alternative way to set it up instead of adding Detox as a dependency to the root `build.gradle` which is what I did.

This is my `detoxrc.json`:

```json
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "skipLegacyWorkersInjection": true,
  "devices": {
    "emulator": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_5_API_30"
      }
    }
  },
  "apps": {
    "android": {
      "type": "android.apk",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd .."
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "android": {
      "device": "emulator",
      "app": "android"
    }
  }
}
```

I know for a fact that my `app-debug.apk` is in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk` because I can see it there. Yet when I run my script for `detox build -c android` this is the output:

```sh
$ yarn e2e:build-android
yarn run v1.22.17
$ detox build --configuration android
detox[19708] INFO:  [build.js] cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..
The system cannot find the path specified.
detox[19708] WARN:  [build.js]

Important: 'detox build' is a convenience shortcut for calling your own build command, as provided in the config file.
Failures in this build command are not the responsibility of Detox. You are responsible for maintaining this command.

detox[19708] ERROR: [cli.js] Command failed: cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The `yarn e2e:build-android` command is just a custom script I defined my root `package.json` as `detox build --configuration android`. So it looks like my problem is that `The system cannot find the path specified`. But as I've stated earlier I can see my `app-debug.apk` in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk` so I know for sure it is in there and that it is the correct path.

I think the issue might have to do with the way my project is structured and where I chose to install the dependencies for detox and jest. I installed detox, jest, & jest-circus in my root `package.json` but this app is a hybrid mobile/web application so the path to my ouput apk is in the `mobile` package. When I ran `yarn e2e:build-android` obviously I was doing that from my root folder which is where detox is installed.

Here is what my project structure looks like:

```
V2 /
|--e2e
|--node_modules
|--packages
|   |--common
|   |--mobile
|   |--web
|--detoxrc.json
|--package.json <--- root pkg.json where I installed detox, jest, & jest-circus as devDep
```

This is my root `package.json` looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "detox": "^19.4.4",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-circus": "^27.5.1",
    "lerna": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "reinstall": "rm -rf ./packages/*/node_modules && rm -rf ./node_modules && yarn",
    "clean": "npx react-native-clean-project",
    "e2e:build-ios": "detox build --configuration ios",
    "e2e:build-android": "detox build --configuration android",
    "e2e:run-ios": "detox test --configuration ios",
    "e2e:run-android": "detox test --configuration android"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/react-native",
      "**/react-native/**",
      "**/react-redux",
      "**/react-redux/**",
      "**/@reduxjs/toolkit",
      "**/@reduxjs/toolkit/**",
      "**/react-dom",
      "**/react-dom/**",
      "**/native-base",
      "**/native-base/**",
      "**/react-native-svg",
      "**/react-native-svg/**",
      "**/react-native-safe-area-context",
      "**/react-native-safe-area-context/**",
      "**/react-native-web",
      "**/react-native-web/**",
      "**/axios",
      "**/axios/**",
      "**/i18next",
      "**/i18next/**",
      "**/react-i18next",
      "**/react-i18next/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

So the full path to my `app-debug.apk` is `V2\packages\mobile\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk` and I've even tried specifying the full path in my `detoxrc.json`'s `binaryBath` field but that did not work either. So I don't know what else the problem could be, but I guess it's possible that Detox just doesn't work with the most recent version of `react-native` which is `v0.67.1` which is what I'm using.

So my official question is what else could this issue be related to?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have copied setup from youtube tutorial. I had similar problem.
Instead of `yarn e2e:build-android`.
run `yarn android`. (this will build your app)
then followed by `yarn e2e:run-android`.

**detoxrc.json**

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "skipLegacyWorkersInjection": true,
  "apps": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.app",
      "binaryPath": "SPECIFY_PATH_TO_YOUR_APP_BINARY",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/JSMarathon.xcworkspace -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build  -scheme JSMarathon"
    },
    "android": {
      "type": "android.apk",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android ; ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug ; cd -"
    }
  },
  "devices": {
    "simulator": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 12"
      }
    },
    "emulator": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_3a_API_30"
      }
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "device": "simulator",
      "app": "ios"
    },
    "android": {
      "device": "emulator",
      "app": "android"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't work. I got the following error when I tried that ERROR: [cli.js] Command failed: jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:ios:).)*$' e2e.